# Synchronize threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have three threads - Thread1 prints "Good", Thread2 prints "Morning" and Thread3 prints "All". How do I use these threads to keep printing “Good Morning All” on the screen continuously?

Comment: you dont. If you want stuff executed in a fixed sequential order then using several threads is a waste of ressources

Comment: @user463035818 you are correct, but what the OP is asking sounds like a variation on a common homework assignment.

Comment: @SolomonSlow on a second thought... i guess the whole point of the exercise is synchronization not threading itself

Answer (score 0):

For one, you are simply wasting resources.

However, assuming that you really need this to accomplish something more important than just printing words, here is a suggestion:

create 3 mutexes (pthread_mutex)

```
pthread_mutex_t m_Good, m_Morning, m_all;
pthread_mutex_init(&m_Good, NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&m_Morning, NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&m_All, NULL);
```

Lock last two mutexes

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&m_Morning);
pthread_mutex_lock(&m_All);
```

In first thread prints its message then unlock second mutex.

```
while(true){
    if(pthread_mutex_lock(&m_Good)==0){
         printf("GOOD ");
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_Morning);
         pthread_mutex_lock(&m_Good);
    }
}
```

- second thread prints message, locks its mutex and unlock third
- third thread prints its message, unlock first mutex and locks third mutex

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple lock-free implementation for forcing sequential execution of threads.  It uses an atomic state variable that can represent four possible states:

- `working` = one of the threads is working
- `ready_for_task1` = it is task1's turn to start working
- `ready_for_task2` = it is task2's turn to start working
- `ready_for_task3` = it is task3's turn to start working

The general idea is to cycle through these states:

```
ready_for_task1 ->
working ->
ready_for_task2 ->
working ->
ready_for_task3 ->
working ->
ready_for_task1 ->
...
```

First part, define the states, declare the global atomic state, and define a guard class that performs the state transitions.  The guard constructor of the guard will "busy" wait by atomically checking for its ready state and switching the state to working.  The guard destructor will set the state to the next task's ready state.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <atomic>

enum State { ready_for_task1, ready_for_task2, ready_for_task3, working };

static std::atomic< State > state_;

class TransitionGuard {
public:
    TransitionGuard(State start, State finish) : finish_(finish) {
        State expecting = start;
        while( !state_.compare_exchange_weak( expecting, working ) ) {
            expecting = start;
            asm("pause");
        }
    }

    ~TransitionGuard() {
        state_.store( finish_ );
    }
private:
    const State finish_;
};
```

Then each thread runs their own loop, printing their word under their respective transition guard.

```
void * task1( void * data )
{
    while( true ) {
        TransitionGuard guard( ready_for_task1, ready_for_task2 );
        printf( "Good" );
    }
}

void * task2( void * data)
{
    while( true ) {
        TransitionGuard guard( ready_for_task2, ready_for_task3 );
        printf( " Morning" );
    }
    return NULL;
}

void * task3( void * data)
{
    while( true ) {
        TransitionGuard guard( ready_for_task3, ready_for_task1 );
        printf( " All\n" );
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And finally, you'll want to initialize the state before creating the threads.

```
int main( int argc, const char ** argv )
{
    state_ = ready_for_task1;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;

    if( pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, task1, NULL ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "thread1 failed to start\n" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, task2, NULL ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "thread2 failed to start\n" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if( pthread_create( &thread3, NULL, task3, NULL ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "thread3 failed to start\n" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL );
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL );
    pthread_join( thread3, NULL );

    fprintf( stderr, "threads joined. exiting.\n" );
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```